# Sort by two fields, with the second being reverse alphabetical one-liner

Tags: ruby

I want to sort a collection such as:

```
[['hello', 'world', 'my'], ['name', 'is', 'foo'], ['bar']]
```

First by size of each element, then by **reverse** alphabetical order of the first element in each element in a one-liner so the result would be

```
[['bar'],['name','is','foo'],['hello','world','my']]
```

I have tried
`groups.sort_by { |group| [group.length, -group.first] }` but the '-' doesn't work here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [['hello', 'world', 'my'], ['name', 'is', 'foo'], ['bar']]

arr.sort_by { |a| [a.size, a.first.reverse] }
  #=> [["bar"], ["name", "is", "foo"], ["hello", "world", "my"]]
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (specifically, the third paragraph), the latter being the method `sort_by` uses to order the two-element arrays.

Comment: I'll go with yours because it's much cleaner and shows the answer using `sort_by`. Thanks @cary!

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by realizing that `sort_by` with multiple fields works as, "first sort by first array item, then if there is a tie, sort by second, and so on". So I changed to `sort` and handled the tie myself with the descending alphabetical order:

```
        groups.sort do |group_a, group_b| 
            result = group_a.length <=> group_b.length
            result.zero? ? group_b.first <=> group_a.first : result
        end.last
```